# In woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook, set_price calculations added twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

Im using Woocommerce and an Event Ticket plugin for my website and ive had to hardcode a select field for when a customer is buying a ticket and based on their selection, the price will go up accordingly.

Majority of it seems to be working fine and the selection is then getting saved as part of the cart data. Im then trying to update the product price once they click the add to cart button so that it adds on the new value to the product price.

Below is what I have and it seems to be updating the price, but annoyingly it is adding the **`$pickup_price`** value twice *(so instead of 3 it adds 6)*.

Strangely, if I change the quantity at the basket stage and update, it gets the correct value, just not when its initially added.

What I am doing wrong and how to prevent this issue?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_pickup_cost', 10, 1 );
function add_pickup_cost( $cart_object, $cart_item_data ) {

     foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

          $wc_product = $cart_item['data'];
          // My custom field which is returning the additional cost
          $pickup_price = $cart_item['pickupOptions'];

          $product_price = method_exists( $wc_product, 'get_price' ) ? floatval($wc_product->get_price()) : floatval($wc_product->price);
          $new_price = $product_price + $pickup_price;
          method_exists( $wc_product, 'set_price' ) ? $wc_product->set_price( $new_price ) : $wc_product->price = $new_price;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed some little thing and I have simplified your code a little bit:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_pickup_cost', 10, 2 );
function add_pickup_cost( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset( $cart_item['pickupOptions'] ) && ! empty( $cart_item['pickupOptions'] ) ){
        // WC_Product object instance
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Get cart item price
        $price  = method_exists( $product, 'get_price' ) ? floatval($product->get_price()) : floatval($product->price);
        $price += (float) $cart_item['pickupOptions']; // Add "Pickup option to the price

        // Set the new price
        if( method_exists( $product, 'set_price' ) ) 
            $product->set_price( $price )
        else
            $product->price = $price;
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: @LocicTheAztec thanks for the reply. I have tried using your code but unfortunately its still adding the additional 'pickupOptions' value twice (so instead of adding on £3, its adding £6).

Comment: @WillL For me this code is working without problem. No duplication… So may be there is something specific somewhere That is causing the issue for you.

Comment: @LocicTheAztec strangely when i click the 'Update Cart' button at the cart or refresh the cart, the price updates to the correct amount. But from that initial Add To Cart, when it takes me there its showing its adding that price twice. Any idea why this might be or a way that i can force an update/refresh after add to cart?

Comment: @WillL This issue seems complex to solve as it can be related to your theme, to some specific plugin or finally to some other custom code...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Add `;` to the `$product->set_price( $price )` code line.